# Make text gradually randomly appear

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm working with the opacity and random() expression. I want a text to appear like randomly pixel by pixel.

For example the text "WEEKEND" I've tried making every single letter their own layer and then use the expression random() on opacity, the problem is it includes the whole letter.

My goal is to randomly fade in the text by pixels, not by the whole layer. How do I replicate this in After Effects?

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to GDSE. Video editing is off-topic here. Use Video Production Stack Exchange instead.  You can flag your own question and ask the mods to migrate it there for you, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure most people who hang around here have seen that in Photoshop one can fade a layer randomly pixel by pixel by having blending mode Dissolve. If you have a text in Photoshop on the top and you set its blending mode Dissolve you can adjust how big part of the text pixels is visible by changing the text layer opacity. The text disappears pixel by pixel (in random order) when the layer opacity is decreased. Try the same in After Effects. Blending mode Dissolve is available also there. You can change the layer opacity with keyframe animation.

But no need to reinvent the wheel. The effect is wanted so much that it's implemented  as a ready to use transition. Its name is Block Dissolve (no idea is it included or should it be purchased as an add-on). See a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O2I2oLgw4E .

In YouTube you can find also numerous more advanced "do it yourself" derivatives of dissolve in pieces. But all this belongs to video editing sites. Hopefully this answer stays a while.